# Space character without "\" in properties file keys

Tags: java

I reed properties file:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("data.ini");
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(reader);
```

My properties file `Key` contains space and I need to put `\` character to read it correctly. Is it possible somehow not place `\` character in properties file and read it in correct way?

Properties file content:

```
aaa\ bbb=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to load properties from an XML file also... makes for neater code.

**properties.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <comment>Sample Properties file in XML</comment>
    <entry key="PropertyWithoutSpaces">Property value</entry>
    <entry key="Property With Spaces">Property value</entry>
</properties>
```

**PropertyTest.java:**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.loadFromXML( new FileInputStream("properties.xml") );

        System.out.println( properties.getProperty("Property With Spaces") );
        System.out.println( properties.getProperty("PropertyWithoutSpaces") );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As described in [load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)) JavaDoc:

> The key contains all of the characters in the line starting with the first non-white space character and up to, but not including, the first unescaped '=', ':', **or white space character** other than a line terminator.

So the answer is no.

Typically keys contain other separator, my experience is that `'.'` is used.

```
aaa.bbb=0
```

Comment: i remeber handling windows file path seperator by first readind the file as raw content handling the escape logic and then feeding to to Properties via input stream. So C:\windows can be read as C:\windows and not as c:windows. Same logic can be used, the file can be left with 'space' but that has to be handled in java before feeding it to Properties class

Comment: I agree, that it is possible to somehow reimplement whole component, but I wouldn't recommend this approach if there is not some strong reason...

Answer (score 1):

you can escape every thing in properties file with Java Unicode,
**\u0020 for whitespace**,use it your problem will get solve.

Answer (score 1):

It is not as clean as using the built in reader, but it is possible with the following code.

```
public static Properties load(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Properties p;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
        p = new Properties();
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int index = line.indexOf('=');
            if (index > 0) {
                String key = line.substring(0, index).trim();
                String value = line.substring(index + 1).trim();
                p.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```